# What was/is the last Blender version supported for Windows/Linux 32-bit computers?

Tags: linux

What would be the last version with 32-bit support? Preferably Linux.

Comment: 2.80 was the final 32 bit build. _(a versão mais recente para suportar 32 bits é 2,80)_

Comment: please ask questions in English and use [an online translator](https://translate.google.com/?sl=pt&tl=en) if needed *(por favor, faça perguntas em inglês e use [um tradutor online](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=pt) se necessário)*

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - Tanks.